# Blender 2.8: How to see multiple view layers at once in viewport?

Tags: 3d-view

I am having difficulty in Blender 2.8 seeing multiple view layers at the same time in my viewport. With my workflow I would more than likely want to be looking at multiple view layers at once in the viewport to see the position and more, of things in relation to everything else. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the blog here: [Blender developers blog in 2017](https://code.blender.org/2017/09/view-layers-and-collections/)

> An exciting future option for the 2.8x roadmap is to use View Layers as compositing units, also for real-time rendering. For simplicity now, we stick to having a single ‘active View Layer’ per Blender window.

And as far as I can see you still have only one active view layer in your blender window at this time.